# create a database from installer file?

Tags: database, winforms, installation

well for example you have build a program, for restaurant, for a cinema, wherever,
now how do you do when, you install your application, the database was installed correctly too? i dont sure but i believe this is a different database? for example a file? 
(talking about sql).

and how different are going to be the queries? cuz i believe i am not going to have the same function on sql server than a file database

and what connection i shall use?
could i use entity framework?

and how capacity  could to have the different file for databases?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a file-based database like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html) that supports SQL queries. There are ADO adapters available as well. The link should take care of the rest of your questions as well.

Comment: what is the maximum size for this database? do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you usually have absolutely no knowledge about target environment, user must configure program to his envronment at install time, or later (af first launch for example, this is much simplier than implement same functionality in installer). User specifies SQL server address (if we are talking about server-based systems) and database name he wants to use. Then database is created programmaticaly using that information.